# Class A amplifier efficiency

Tags: power, amplifier, efficiency, power-amplifier, class-a

[image]

I am trying to simulate this class A amplifier using Multisim. I need help to measure the power loss and then calculate the efficiency. I don't have to calculate the power loss; I could just use something to measure it but I haven't got a clue how to do that.

Comment: You can't compute the efficiency without knowing what the input signal is, for one thing. With no input signal the efficiency is 0%. Also, I hate Multisim and haven't used it in a very very long time. But isn't there a way for you to ask it to compute the power in RC1 and also the power from Vcc?

Comment: Are you asking us how to use Multisim? Can you measure the current provided by the VCC supply? Can you measure the current and voltage delivered to the load?

Comment: You know the supply voltage, but you don't know the supply current. Does that suggest a way forward? Once you know the power being supplied, work on calculating the output power.

Comment: @Frantisek Can you edit the question and write a specific question?